# Jmeter performance testing for application running under LAN network

Tags: jmeter, lan

Is it possible to test an application which is running under LAN network using JMETER? If it is possible to do so, then what settings I need to do? Please suggest..

Comment: what kind of application is that? If it is web-based, yes,  you can use JMeter.  But you need to provide more information to get your issue clarified.

Answer (score 0):

I have some points on your question,

- Apache JMeter may be used to test functional and performance both on
  static and dynamic resources (Servlets, Application servers, Data
  Bases and Queries, JDBC, Web Services and more,).
- It can be used to simulate a heavy load on a server, network or
  object to test its strength or to analyze overall performance under
  different load types.
- Jmeter can also use to perform a functional test on websites,
  databases, LDAPs, webservices etc.
- Jmeter also supports distributed load testing with different
  machines.

**Ans:**

You can use jmeter for load testing the applications(specified above) in LAN Network using  LAN URL&port number of application you are using.

Comment: How to use LAN URL and port number of the application in JMeter? Please explain..

Comment: For example an Apache tomcat on a machine with IP - 192.168.0.55 & Port-8080 and your machine is with IP-192.168.0.10 in same local network; you can access the tomcat server dashboard by hitting the URL http://192.168.0.55:8080/. If your application deployed on that Apache tomcat server you can access the application by hitting http://192.168.0.55:8080/myapplication/.  So you can use this application URL to crate test plan for Apache Jmeter situated in you machine(192.168.0.10).

Comment: Note: If Your local network using any proxy, add proxy to Jmeter TestPlan or start Jmeter in Command Line with Proxy Arguments otherwise you can use bypass/No proxy settings in machine network settings. Hopes yu understood my point. 
I dont have deep knowledge in customising jmeter properties file, I need to refer & google on the answer given Mr.Dimitri.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible.

`jmeter.properties` file which lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation has 2 properties which are commented out:

```
#Define characters per second > 0 to emulate slow connections
#httpclient.socket.http.cps=0
#httpclient.socket.https.cps=0
```

Following values can be used to simulate LAN:

> Ethernet LAN, 10 Mbit/s: **1280000**
>
> Fast Ethernet : 100 Mbit/s: **12800000**
>
> Gigabit Ethernet : 1 Gbit/s: **128000000**
>
> 10 Gigabit Ethernet : 10 Gbit/s: **1280000000**
>
> 100 Gigabit Ethernet : 100 Gbit/s: **12800000000**

You can set this property either by uncommenting relevant property for your protocol in "jmeter.properties" file, putting amended properties in "user.properties" file, or set them in command line as:

```
jmeter -Jhttpclient.socket.http.cps=12800000
```

To throttle bandwidth limiting it to 100 Mbit/S

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details on how to deal with JMeter Properties.